# Loading OboutInc.Window with magnification 110% says "Window/Dialog style could not be loaded."

Tags: obout

Good morning everyone, the style loading fails, when I use a 110% magnification (only 110%, with other values it works), it doesn't matter if Chrome or Edge. In my opinion a rounding error in the recalculation within the control, and I really have no idea how to fix it.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Test.aspx.vb" Inherits="Test" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="obout_Window_NET" Namespace="OboutInc.Window" TagPrefix="owd" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function OpenWindow() {
            Window1.Open();
        }
    </script>

<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="mybutton" Text="Test" OnClientClick="OpenWindow();"></asp:LinkButton>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
<owd:Window ID="Window1" DebugMode="false" runat="server" Title="Test"
    Url="" IsModal="true" IsResizable="true"
    VisibleOnLoad="false" ShowStatusBar="true" StyleFolder="~/Obout/wdstyles/default" 
    Overflow="AUTO" >
    TestWindow
</owd:Window>

</html>
```